# Does joint integrability imply marginal integrability for non-negative continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R_+$ is a non-negative continuous function and that $$\int_{y\in\mathbb R}\int_{x\in\mathbb R}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy<\infty.$$ Is it true that $$\int_{x\in\mathbb R}f(x,y)\,\mathrm d x<\infty$$ for *all* $y\in\mathbb R$, as opposed to merely *almost all* $y\in\mathbb R$?

My hunch is that the answer is affirmative given the continuity of $f$, but I can come up with neither a proof nor a counterexample. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Consider the function
$$
f(x,y) = \exp\left(-\left|\sqrt{\smash{|y|}\vphantom{L}} \cdot x\right|\right) \cdot (1 - y^2) \cdot 1_{(-1,1)}(y).
$$

This is continuous and integrable, but $f(x , 0) \equiv 1$ is not integrable.

Comment: Great counterexample, thank you!